# Remote Desktop Manager cannot connect where mstsc can

Tags: windows-10, networking, remote-desktop

I'm looking for a Remote Desktop Manager. The ones I tried (RDCMan, mRemoteNG, RoyalTS, Devolutions RDM, Dameware and Terminals) all cannot connect to the remote host

> An authentication error has occurred. The function requested is not
> supported
>
> Remote computer: xxxxx.xxxxx.nl
> This could be due to CredSSP encryption oracle remediation. For more information, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=866660

If however I connect using mstsc the connection succeeds and I can access the remote hosts desktop. All these RD Managers seem to work the same way and all fail.

Anyone any clue?

Comment: [AnyDesk](https://anydesk.com/en) might be a workaround till you find a better one. No need to install, runs directly from the .exe file. Unfortunately it doesn't run as a service, it needs to be running for connection to be available.

Comment: There is some deeper problem here, as for example RoyalTS actually embeds the same system object for connecting as does mstsc.

Comment: @Peregrino69 what a horrible workaround. MSTSC works so there really is no reason to use a different tool. The question is why those managers, which just RDP, would fail when RDP using MSTSC works.

Comment: @Seth Thank you for the kind words!

Comment: With RemoteMG there is the option to set a CredSSP flag per connection. It might be worth it to checkout whenever that makes a difference or not. The config section on the left has a separate tab for the "Default Properties". With MSTSC are you using an RD gateway or is it a direct connection?

Comment: I found that when I use a different username format (before <domain>\<username> now <username>@xxxxxx.nl I get a connection. Very strange.